# Trim doesn't seem to work with Rich Text

Tags: .net, vb.net, string

There is a RichTextBox I'm saving as a byte array in sql, and noticed that I'm unable to remove whitespace using trim.

I've tried many variations:

```
Dim array() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(RichTextBox1.Rtf.TrimStart())

Dim array() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(RichTextBox1.Rtf.TrimStart(" "))

Dim array() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(RichTextBox1.Rtf.TrimStart(" "c))

... save array to db...
```

When reading it back, the RTF still comes back with white space.  Am I missing something?

Comment: There shouldn't be any white space at the end or the beginning.  What are you trying to remove?

Comment: White space that the user types into the textbox.  It would not make sense to have a trim for rtf markup would it?

Comment: I think varocarbas understood your question better than I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trim functions are meant for `Text`, not for `Rtf`.

```
RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.TrimStart()
Dim array() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(RichTextBox1.Rtf)
```

Comment: Yes I suppose that's it.  It just took me off guard that Rtf.Trim exists when it serves no practical use.

Comment: @Dave RTF is just a string, so you get all the extensions you would for Text, too.

Comment: @Dave LarsTech is right. The problem is that affecting the string essence of rtf does not have any influence on its "style-defining essence". The fact of triming the rtf code does not imply that you are trimming the text which this code is decorating: the .Text of the RTB

Comment: Yeah I understand.  I guess RTF being merely a string is not what I would have expected.

Comment: Varocarabas, thanks for the answer, it's right, but the code solution seems to wipe out any formatting, so I'm going to have to find another way to remove the white space from RTF.

Comment: @Dave see it as the HTML code of a webpage: the browser translate all this into nice-looking stuff but, actually, it is not more than text.

Comment: @Dave (my nick is varocarbas) Sorry but my solution just does what yours was doing. Your code is the one wiping out the formatting :)